# Visual Studio SSRS Calendar Report Details Not Grouping

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying to build a calendar report in Visual Studio Reporting Services. The issue I am having is that the IDs aren't grouping together in the same cell. I'm sure this has to do with how I am bringing in the data but is there a way to render it correctly? Essentially I want one row per week with all the applicable IDs in the applicable cell.

[Screenshot of report output as is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POutc.png)

[Report Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkCrj.png)

[Sample of my query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6nt6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've done in this situation.

1. Add a ROW_NUMBER() with a partition on the ID
2. Group on the ROW_NUMBER() rather than the ID.

So, in your SQL query, add another column that might look something like this:

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Date ORDER BY ID, Date) RowNum
```

If that doesn't work, or you're not familiar with the window functions, post your query.